# Why is Angular not updating with a JSON file?

Tags: angularjs, json, object

I'm trying to use a simple Angular JS app to load data from a JSON file to a website but it does not work.

The JSON file is:

```
{"a": "a"}
```

The Angular app is:

```
var app = angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", ["ser", function(ser) {
    var vm = this;

    ser.getInfo().then(function(data) {
      vm.data = data;
    });
  }])
  .service("ser", function() {
    this.getInfo = function() {
      return $.get("models/model.json");
    };
  });
```

The HTML is:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl as ctrl">
  <p>{{ctrl.data.a}}</p>
</div>
```

I'm not getting any console errors. I think the problem is related to the lexical scoping for the controller due to the asynchronous `getInfo().then()` call in the controller, I checked `vm` inside the function and it is being loaded correctly but doesn't seem to change the `ctrl` object or Angular is not updating when it does.

I'm serving the app locally.

It works sometimes but most times it doesn't. I can get it to work using `$scope` but I'm trying to figure out why it's not working now.

Comment: "I'm serving the app locally". Do you mean from the file system? Because that won't work, since you can't use an HTTP request over the file system. See [this question's answers for more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10752055/215552)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I'm using simplehttpserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using `jQuery` for the ajax. If you modify the scope outside of angular context you need to notify angular to run a digest

Change to using angular `$http` to avoid such issues

```
var app = angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", ["ser", function(ser) {
    var vm = this;

    ser.getInfo().then(function(response) {
      vm.data = response.data;
    });
  }])
  .service("ser", ['$http', function($http) {
    this.getInfo = function() {
      return $http.get("models/model.json");
    };
  }]);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/JnJZP6tU90tIszM0oDzA?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If it works with $scope that means that without it, Angular is not aware that you performed an asynchronous operation.

I think the following line is using jQuery: `return $.get("models/model.json");`

So even if you get your data from your function `getInfo`, it isn't synchronized with the view via `vm.data = data;`